# Not able to display web page in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This seems a bit strange and new problem to me, I am trying to run a program on Apache server, the server runs fine but when Eclipse try to open the web page, instead of opening it shows a pop up to either save or open in external browser, now when I try to open in external browser it again shows the same pop up and when I save it and again try to open it it shows the same pop up.

Simply saying I am not able to view my web page in anyway.

Is there a problem with my Eclipse or is there something I need to change in my Eclipse?

Comment: have you tried setting up default browser ? Is it a webapp archetype or a dynamic web project?

Comment: You have to install the [webtools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) .

Comment: @VaibhavShukla it is a dynamic web project.
same issue with default browser also.

Comment: @user714965 i checked in link "About Eclipse" in "Help" tab and the plugin is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using eclipse indigo or juno. You should try and set the default browser by

**`Windows-> Web Browser ->`**

This will list something like this [image] ,

where the `internal browser` is your eclipse default browser which opens the webpage within eclipse itself. You can set it to any other browser as well.

Also, do check your `web.xml` file for `welcome-file` probably `index.jsp` and it should not be inside your `WEB-INF`. Sync your project with your tomcat server by adding the project to it and run your project directly on server. It will open up the welcome page.

Try this out. See if that helps

Comment: hey can't see this link in my eclipse although i can see that eclipse is using **Default system web browser** by going to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Web Browser. The radio button is checked on **Use internal web browser** and checkbox checked on **Default system web browser**.  And regarding the directory structure everything is fine.

Comment: Thats what i said, which eclipse are you using ? Try using indigo or juno and you'll see that option

Comment: i am using indigo, but not able to see that option.

Comment: Then do this:  **Windows->Open Perspective -> Others ->Web** , you'll enter web perspective and then you could go on with the solution i mentioned in the image above. You'll see that web browser option